# What is the significance of the 3rd, 7th and 30th day after Catholic funerals?

Tags: catholicism, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, funeral

I was reading a 1952 missal and wondering about some of the customs, one notable one I saw was that there was a particular commemoration that is supposed to be celebrated on the 3rd, 7th and 30th day after a funeral.

Is there any particular significance in these days in Scripture or Tradition? How would someone go about getting a Mass said like this? Assuming there are funerals every other week in an active parish, wouldn't every other Mass wind up being this kind of commemoration?

Comment: 30 days---Month's Mind Mass---https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month%27s_mind#:~:text=A%20month%27s%20mind%20is%20a,the%20day%20as%20commemorationis%20dies.